# Remove Sheet Parent Array Import to Collection or Array on Laravel Excel Package

Tags: arrays, excel, laravel, import, package

I want import Excel but only on sheet index[0], but when I use toCollection or toArray method the rows wrapped on sheet index array:

I want remove the wrapped parent array, how to do this?

Here is my code:

`Import.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class Import implements SkipsEmptyRows,
                        WithCalculatedFormulas,
                        WithMultipleSheets
{
    use Importable;

    /**
     * Select sheet by index and how they are
     * mapped to specific import object.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            0 => new static(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$filePath = 'import-excel.xlsx';
$import = new Import();
$rows = $import->toCollection($filePath);

dd($rows->toArray());
```

Expected Result:

```
[0] => Array(
    [0] => *Contact Name
    [1] => *Contact Email
    [2] => *Contact Address
)

[1] => Array (
    [0] => Talia Oktaviani S.Psi
    [1] => nova03@yahoo.com
    [2] => Ds. Abdul No. 618 Tarakan 11408 KalU
)
```

Actual Result:

```
Array(  <== ***I want remove this.***
    [0] => Array(  <== ***I want remove this.***
        [0] => Array(
            [0] => *Contact Name
            [1] => *Contact Email
            [2] => *Contact Address
        )

        [1] => Array (
            [0] => Talia Oktaviani S.Psi
            [1] => nova03@yahoo.com
            [2] => Ds. Abdul No. 618 Tarakan 11408 KalU
        )
    )  <== ***I want remove this.***
)  <== ***I want remove this.***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete if use collapse function

```
$filePath = 'import-excel.xlsx';
$import = new Import();
$rows = $import->toCollection($filePath)->collapse();

dd($rows->toArray());
```